# React Native Dropdown Picker switch between variables

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Is there a way that you can use dropdown picker and switch between variables?
The variables are checkboxes.
So there are two values in the dropdown picker, and they sa called *Hourly View* and *Daily View*.
When one of them is selected there needs to be viewed different options for selection (checkboxes).

Here is the example of the code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, CheckBox } from 'react-native';
import { Picker } from '@react-native-picker/picker';


const HourlyView = () => {
    return (

        <View>

            <View>
                <CheckBox /><Text>Temperature (2m)</Text>
                <CheckBox /><Text>Relative Humidity (2m)</Text>
                <CheckBox /><Text>Dewpoint (2m)</Text>
                <CheckBox /><Text>Apparent Temperature</Text>
                <CheckBox /><Text>Sealevel Pressure</Text>
                <CheckBox /><Text>Precipitation</Text>
                <CheckBox /><Text>Wealthercode</Text>
                <CheckBox /><Text>Snow Depth</Text>
                <CheckBox /><Text>Freezinglevel Height</Text>
            </View>

        </View>
    );
};


const Details = () => {

    const [choosedValue, setChoosedValue] = useState();

    return (

        <View style={styles.container}>

            <Text style={styles.containerTitle}>Meteorologic data for City</Text>

            <Picker
                selectedValue={choosedValue}
                style={styles.dropdownSelect}
                onValueChange={(itemValue) => {setChoosedValue(itemValue);}}
            >

                <Picker.Item label="Hourly" value="hourly" />
                <Picker.Item label="Daily" value="daily" />

            </Picker>

            <View>
                {choosedValue} 
            </View>

        </View>

    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    containerTitle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 40,
        paddingTop: 50,
        color: '#51697f',
    },
    dropdownSelect: {
        height: 50,
        width: 200,
    }
});

export default Details;
```

I tried calling the function in the *<Picker.Item label="Hourly" **value={HourlyView()}** />* and returns **[object Object]**

I only writed the code for the Hourly View the Daily would be the same.

Any advice how to solve this?
I tried googling and didn't find and any solution.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a proper way to render components.  Instead, use conditional rendering to render your hourlyview and dailyview component.
https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: @caslawter I was thinking of using it that way but I decide to stick to a different method. Instead a create a BottomTabNavigator a every tab is importing different function. And it is working good.